# Pass multiple data and datatype from a childform to a parent and save to database

Tags: c#

In my MdiForm I have a menubar that has btnSave on it. I would like to save the data created in my childform that is active by clicking the btnSave on the midForm menubar. I have these classes to save the data to the database:

StudentBal.cs

```
internal class StudentBal
{
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CityAddress { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string PlaceOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string TelNo { get; set; }
    public string Father { get; set; }
    public string Mother { get; set; }
    public string ParentsAddress { get; set; }
    public string EmployersName { get; set; }
    public string EmplyerTelNo { get; set; }
    public string GuardiansName { get; set; }
    public string GuradiansAddress { get; set; }
    public byte[] StudentImage { get; set; }
    public string WorkAddress { get; set; }

    public int InsertStudent(StudentBal bal)
    {
        var dal = new StudentDal();
       return dal.InsertStudent(bal);
    }
```

StudentDal.cs

```
public int InsertStudent(StudentBal bal)
    {
        const string query =
            @"INSERT INTO students VALUES(@DateAdded, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @CityAddress, @HomeAddress, @Nationality,
                                @MaritalStatus, @DateOfBirth, @PlaceOfBirth, @TelNo, @Father, @Mother, 
                                @ParentsAddress, @EmployersName, @EmployersTelNo, @GuardiansName, 
                                @GuardiansAddress, @StudentImage, @WorkAddress)";
        using (_cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _cn))
        {
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAdded", Convert.ToDateTime(bal.DateAdded).ToShortDateString());
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", bal.FirstName);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", bal.MiddleName);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", bal.LastName);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityAddress", bal.CityAddress);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", bal.HomeAddress);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", bal.Nationality);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", bal.MaritalStatus);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", bal.DateOfBirth);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaceOfBirth", bal.PlaceOfBirth);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelNo", bal.TelNo);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Father", bal.Father);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mother", bal.Mother);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParentsAddress", bal.ParentsAddress);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployersName", bal.EmployersName);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployersTelNo", bal.EmplyerTelNo);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuardiansName", bal.GuardiansName);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuardiansAddress", bal.GuradiansAddress);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentImage", bal.StudentImage);
            _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkAddress", bal.WorkAddress);
            _cn.Open();
            return(_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
        }
    }
```

This is in my AddStudent Form

```
 private void btnSaveInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox2.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
        if (!CheckTextBox()) return;
        var bal = new StudentBal
        {
            CityAddress = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCityAddress.Text) ? "N/A" : txtCityAddress.Text,
            DateAdded = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
            DateOfBirth = txtDateOfBirth.Text,
            EmployersName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmployersName.Text) ? "N/A" : txtEmployersName.Text,
            EmplyerTelNo = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmpContactNumber.Text) ? "N/A" : txtEmpContactNumber.Text,
            Father = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFathersName.Text) ? "N/A" : txtFathersName.Text,
            FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
            GuardiansName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGuardiansName.Text) ? "N/A" : txtGuardiansName.Text,
            GuradiansAddress = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGuardiansAddress.Text) ? "N/A" : txtGuardiansAddress.Text,
            HomeAddress = txtHomeAddress.Text,
            LastName = txtLastName.Text,
            MaritalStatus = txtMaritalStatus.Text,
            MiddleName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMiddleName.Text) ? "N/A" : txtMiddleName.Text,
            Mother = txtMothersName.Text,
            Nationality = txtNationality.Text,
            ParentsAddress = txtParentsAddress.Text,
            PlaceOfBirth = txtPlaceOfBirth.Text,
            TelNo = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTelNo.Text) ? "N/A" : txtTelNo.Text,
            StudentImage = pic,
            WorkAddress = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtWorkAddress.Text) ? "N/A" : txtWorkAddress.Text, 
        };
        var result = bal.InsertStudent(bal);
        if (result > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Data successfully added.");
        }
        var obj = (MdiForm)Application.OpenForms["MdiForm"];
        if (obj != null) obj.FillComboBox(); 
    }
```

I would need to pass all the information from my childform(AddStudent) to the  parentform(MdiFOrm) so I can save all the details by clicking on the btnSave in the menubar. I tried creating a public method (SaveDetails()) that can be invoked in the parent form like so:

```
AddStudent add = new AddStudent();
add.SaveDetails();
```

But doing the code above will create a new instance and will not save the active childform that has the values to be saved. If there is a way to call a method in the active childform without instantiating (var addStudent = new AddStudent();) that will be great. 
Making the method public static won't work in this scenario.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: but you can give the parent to the child inside contructor and then make a callback

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain more or give an example.

Comment: inside your child, you add a membervariable from type of your parent. then you give a reverence of your parent to your child...you only have to do that one time, so it makes sense to do that inside the contructor. You also need a public method inside your parent (a callback method) which you give over the information you want to save. the child is now able to call that method over the membervariable of the parent...

Comment: or didn't I understood the question?

Comment: side note: Always specify column names when writing an insert into statement. otherwise once a column is added your application will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the abstract example of doing a callback:

```
public class Parent
{
    public void CreateChild()
    {
        Child childNew = new Child(this); //here you give over the parents reverence
    }

    public void SaveStuff(int number)
    {
        //here you can save the number
    }
}


class Child
{
    private Parent parent;
    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void PressOkButton()
    {
        this.parent.SaveStuff(4); //here you are doing the callback
    }
}
```

Comment: SThank you. Now how do I pass multiple values into SaveStuff? If you will see in the properties of StudentBal, aside from the strings and int, I have an array of Byte "byte[] StudentImage {get; set;} as well. In your example it is only one number and I have already made it to work. It's just this one when I have multiple data to pass. Array?

Comment: you can replace "int number" with "StudentBal bal"

Comment: if the Child have a reverence of the parent, then you can call the InsertStudent method with (parent.InsertStudent())

Comment: Oh! I get it! Thanks!